# Load popup on page load with one condition / BPOPUP plugin

Tags: jquery, popup, load, bpopup

I need help to solve a problem I ve. I need to have a popup that will display information with one condition. I succeed to implement it but it requires a click on a button. what I need is that it appears after the page is loaded if it verifies one  condition.

here is the code, thanks in advance.

```
<?php 
$set = 0;

if( $this->dx_auth->is_logged_in())
{
    $userid = $this->dx_auth->get_user_id();
    if( $list->user_id == $userid )
    {
        $set = 1;
    }
}
?>


 <?php if($set): ?>
<div id="new_hosting_actions">
<h2> <?php echo anchor ('rooms/edit/'.$room_id,translate("Edit this Listing")); ?> <span    class="smaller"> <?php echo translate("Upload photos, change pricing, edit details"); ?>   </span> </h2>
 <hr class="toolbar_separator" />
 <h2> <?php echo anchor ('calendar/single/'.$room_id,translate("Calendar")); ?><span class="smaller"> <?php echo translate("Change the availability of").' '.'"'.$title.'"'; ?>  </span> </h2>
 <hr class="toolbar_separator" />
<h2> <?php echo anchor('users/edit', translate("Update Your Profile"))?> <span class="smaller"> <?php echo translate("Upload a new profile image and change your profile");?> </span> </h2>
```

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 

   ;(function($) {
        $(function() {

        $('#my-button2').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.element_to_pop_up2').bPopup({
        closeClass:'close',
        fadeSpeed: 'slow', //can be a string ('slow'/'fast') or int
        followSpeed: 1500, //can be a string ('slow'/'fast') or int
        modalColor: 'black',
        contentContainer:'.content',

         zIndex: 1,
         modalClose: true
            });
        });
     });
 })(jQuery);
  </script>
 <button id="my-button2" type="button" class="button5">POP IT UP</button>

        <div id="element_to_pop_up" class="element_to_pop_up2" style="display:none">
          <div id="status">

         <div id="dates" class="book_it_section" >
          <input id="hosting_id" name="hosting_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $room_id; ?>" />
            <h2>Send Message </h2>

            <div class="messagearea">


            </div>
               <p><div class="border"></div></p>
            <div class="send">           
            </div>
         </div>         
        </div>
        <a class="close" href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/fancy_close.png" alt="close" width="45" height="45" /> </a>       
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done using an actual popup; browsers will block them from opening if they aren't triggered by an action by the user (such as clicking).

You could, however, use an overlay instead. There are no doubt a number of jQuery plugins that you could use for overlays, but I'm not familiar enough with any to provide recommendations.